# Need help finding out why the texture doesn't load

Tags: java, opengl

Trying to find a way to render a simple 2D image in Java using OpenGL I stumbled upon a more or less understandable class that does all of the image loading for you which I could not understand how to do. I believe it belongs to a person named Krythic and I assume that it works fine, I even preinted out the height and width of the image it is reading to see if it reads the proper image, which it does.
But here is said class nonetheless (I don't fully understand how it works):

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL12;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class TextureLoader {
    private static final int BYTES_PER_PIXEL = 4;//3 for RGB, 4 for RGBA
    public static int loadTexture(BufferedImage image){
    int[] pixels = new int[image.getWidth() * image.getHeight()];

    image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels, 0, image.getWidth());

    ByteBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(image.getWidth() * image.getHeight() * BYTES_PER_PIXEL); //4 for RGBA, 3 for RGB

    for(int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++){
            int pixel = pixels[y * image.getWidth() + x];
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF));     // Red component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF));      // Green component
            buffer.put((byte) (pixel & 0xFF));               // Blue component
            buffer.put((byte) ((pixel >> 24) & 0xFF));    // Alpha component. Only for RGBA
        }
    }

    buffer.flip(); //FOR THE LOVE OF GOD DO NOT FORGET THIS

    // You now have a ByteBuffer filled with the color data of each pixel.
    // Now just create a texture ID and bind it. Then you can load it using
    // whatever OpenGL method you want, for example:

    int textureID = glGenTextures(); //Generate texture ID
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID); //Bind texture ID

    //Setup wrap mode
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    //Setup texture scaling filtering
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    //Send texel data to OpenGL
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    //Return the texture ID so we can bind it later again
    return textureID;
}

public static BufferedImage loadImage(String loc)
{
    try {
        return ImageIO.read(Main.class.getResource(loc));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Error Handling Here
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is the code I wrote thinking it would render the image on a quad, and that is probably where the problem lies.

```
while ( glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == GL_FALSE ) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            BufferedImage image = TextureLoader.loadImage("test.png");
            int textureID = TextureLoader.loadTexture(image);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);               
            glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
            glVertex2f(-1f, -1f);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
            glVertex2f( 0f, -1f);
            glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
            glVertex2f( 0f,  0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
            glVertex2f(-1f,  0f);
            glEnd();

            glfwSwapBuffers(window);

            glfwPollEvents();
        }
```

So it draws a quad in the lower left corner of the screen as it did before, but it's white and the texture is supposed to be brown. It doesn't give me any exceptions so I don't know exactly where I messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable textures with

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```